# how to open a file in C (fopen/fread)

Tags: c, fopen

I have an embedded board (beagleboard-xm) that runs ubuntu 12.04, I would like to read one GPIO input if it is logic 1 or 0. How can I implement `cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio139/value` in C? (**value** file stores 0 or 1)
I open the file by:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio139/value", "rb");
```

what do I need to do next?

Comment: You should just be able to read one byte and branch based on its value.  Isn't this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read one byte, or until eof:

```
 char buffer[32]; // Very long number!

 if (NULL == (fp = fopen(FILENAME, "rb")))
 {
     // TODO: return a suitable error/perror
     return -1;
 }
 bytesread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer)-1, fp);
 fclose(fp);
 if (!bytesread)
 {
     // Nothing at all was read
     // TODO: return error
     return -2;
 }
 // This is in case you want the byte interpreted from ASCII
 // otherwise you'd just return buffer[0], or (*(DATATYPE *)buffer)[0].
 buffer[bytesread] = 0x0;
 return atol(buffer);
```

This code is actually not that general, in that many hardware devices will implement a blocking data channel - that is, if you try to read more data than it's there, the fread will block until data becomes available. In such a case, just dimension the buffer to the maximum number of bytes you need, plus one.

The plus one, and the corresponding -1 in the fread, are only there for the case in which the data you read is rendered as ASCII, i.e., "128" is three ASCII bytes "1", "2", "8" and maybe even a carriage return, instead of a binary 0x80. In this case, the buffer is zero-terminated to make it a C string on which atol may operate to retrieve a decimal number.

If what is needed is a binary value, then no such conversion is needed, and one can read the full buffer without adjustments, avoid setting the last plus one byte to zero, and just return a cast value from the buffer; or buffer[0] if only one byte is needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read one character, try this:

```
int value = fgetc(fp);
/* error checking */
value = value - '0';
```

Answer (score 2):

After attempting to open the file, you check that the `fopen()` succeeded.

Then you can use any of the `stdio` functions to read the data:

- `getc()`
- `fgetc()`
- `fgets()`
- `fread()`

and probably others too.  You might be looking at the `scanf()` family, but most probably won't be using them, for example.  Which is most appropriate depends on the data that is read; is it text or is it binary.  If it is a single character, then `getc()`; if it is text and line-oriented, maybe `fgets()`; if binary, probably `fread()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your Linux headers, than I would recommend you to access GPIO using Linux API.

Include this in your file:

`#include <linux/gpio.h>`

Now you have access to functions like:

- `int gpio_is_valid(int number);`
- `int gpio_get_value(unsigned gpio);`
- `void gpio_set_value(unsigned gpio, int value);`

In your case you can just write this:

```
int io_ret = -1;
if (gpio_is_valid(139))
    io_ret = gpio_get_value(139);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think it will be better if you used:

```
system("echo  /sys/class/gpio/gpio139/value >> temp.txt ");
```

after that it is easy you can just extract the value from `temp.txt` which will be either `0` or `1`